# High Memory consumption by while running console application with large database in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, out-of-memory

I'm working on console application which is responsible to only pull data from sql server. For that I've used sqlreader to read retrieve data very fast.

My concern is that, when I run console application, that application taking too much memory. It keeps increasing. I've checked Task manager but there is no luck. I did not find any processes that takes too much memory. After some googling I found [Rammap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) tool. According to that tool, AWE is taking too much memory. It takes 7 GB of 8 GB memory. but it did not release memory and after that query has not been served by sql server and gets timeout expired error.

However, I googled for AWE but did not find any useful information related to my issue.

So, Why is it taking too much memory?

Here is my sample code to retrieve a data.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get Products 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productIds">Product Ids</param>
    /// <returns>Product List</returns>
    public IList<Product> GetProducts(IList<int> productIds)
    {
        try
        {
            //pass product identifiers as comma-delimited string
            string commaSeparatedProductIds = "";
            if (productIds != null)
            {
                commaSeparatedProductIds = String.Join(",", productIds);
            }

            string query = "GetProducts";

            List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();


            //Open connection
            connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();

            //create a command object
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                //command to execute
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductIds", commaSeparatedProductIds);


                //database call
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        //TODO Uncomment se name in sp
                        Product product = new Product();

                        product.Id = reader.GetValue<int>("Id");
                        product.Name = reader.GetValue<string>("Name");
                        product.ShortDescription = reader.GetValue<string>("ShortDescription");
                        product.FullDescription = reader.GetValue<string>("FullDescription");
                        product.ProductTypeId = reader.GetValue<int>("ProductTypeId");
                        product.CreatedOnUtc = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("CreatedOnUtc");
                        product.Sku = reader.GetValue<string>("Sku");
                        product.AllowCustomerReviews = reader.GetValue<bool>("AllowCustomerReviews"); Convert.ToBoolean(reader["AllowCustomerReviews"].ToString());
                        product.ApprovedRatingSum = reader.GetValue<int>("ApprovedRatingSum");
                        product.ApprovedTotalReviews = reader.GetValue<int>("ApprovedTotalReviews");
                        product.VendorId = reader.GetValue<int>("VendorId");

                        product.IsTaxExempt = reader.GetValue<bool>("IsTaxExempt"); Convert.ToBoolean(reader["IsTaxExempt"].ToString());
                        product.TaxCategoryId = reader.GetValue<int>("TaxCategoryId");
                        product.OldPrice = reader.GetValue<decimal>("OldPrice");
                        product.Price = reader.GetValue<decimal>("Price");
                        product.DisableBuyButton = reader.GetValue<bool>("DisableBuyButton"); Convert.ToBoolean(reader["DisableBuyButton"].ToString());
                        product.AvailableForPreOrder = reader.GetValue<bool>("AvailableForPreOrder"); Convert.ToBoolean(reader["AvailableForPreOrder"].ToString());
                        product.SpecialPrice = reader.GetValue<decimal>("SpecialPrice");
                        product.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc = reader.GetValue<DateTime?>("SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc");
                        product.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc = reader.GetValue<DateTime?>("SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc");
                        product.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc = reader.GetValue<DateTime?>("AvailableStartDateTimeUtc");
                        product.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc = reader.GetValue<DateTime?>("AvailableEndDateTimeUtc");
                        product.CallForPrice = reader.GetValue<bool>("CallForPrice"); Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CallForPrice"].ToString());
                        product.CustomerEntersPrice = reader.GetValue<bool>("CustomerEntersPrice"); Convert.ToBoolean(reader["CustomerEntersPrice"].ToString());

                        product.VendorId = reader.GetValue<int>("VendorId");
                        product.VendorName = reader.GetValue<string>("VendorName");

                        product.SeName = reader.GetValue<string>("SeName");

                        product.Category = reader.GetValue<string>("Category");
                        product.Manufacturer = reader.GetValue<string>("Manufacturer");
                        product.Tag = reader.GetValue<string>("Tag");

                        product.Picture = reader.GetValue<string>("Picture");

                        productList.Add(product);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }

                //close up the reader, we're done saving results
                reader.Close();

                //close connection
                connection.Close();

                return productList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HelperClass.CatchException(ex);
            return new List<Product>();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

/// <summary>
/// Helper class for SqlDataReader, which allows for the calling code to retrieve a value in a generic fashion.
/// </summary>
public static class SqlReaderHelper
{
    private static bool IsNullableType(Type theValueType)
    {
        return (theValueType.IsGenericType && theValueType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value, of type T, from the SqlDataReader, accounting for both generic and non-generic types.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">T, type applied</typeparam>
    /// <param name="theReader">The SqlDataReader object that queried the database</param>
    /// <param name="theColumnName">The column of data to retrieve a value from</param>
    /// <returns>T, type applied; default value of type if database value is null</returns>
    public static T GetValue<T>(this SqlDataReader theReader, string theColumnName)
    {
        // Read the value out of the reader by string (column name); returns object
        object theValue = theReader[theColumnName];

        // Cast to the generic type applied to this method (i.e. int?)
        Type theValueType = typeof(T);

        // Check for null value from the database
        if (DBNull.Value != theValue)
        {
            // We have a null, do we have a nullable type for T?
            if (!IsNullableType(theValueType))
            {
                // No, this is not a nullable type so just change the value's type from object to T
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theValue, theValueType);
            }
            else
            {
                // Yes, this is a nullable type so change the value's type from object to the underlying type of T
                NullableConverter theNullableConverter = new NullableConverter(theValueType);

                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(theValue, theNullableConverter.UnderlyingType);
            }
        }

        // The value was null in the database, so return the default value for T; this will vary based on what T is (i.e. int has a default of 0)
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Here is Stored Procedure

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Dharmik
-- Create date: 29-01-2014
-- Description: Get products for indexing
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProducts] 
    @ProductIds nvarchar(MAX) = NULL

AS
BEGIN


if(@ProductIds is not null)
BEGIN   


CREATE TABLE #Product(
    Id [int] ,
    Name [nvarchar](400) NOT NULL,
    ShortDescription [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    FullDescription [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    ProductTypeId [int] NOT NULL,
    CreatedOnUtc [datetime] NOT NULL,
    Sku [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    AllowCustomerReviews [bit] NOT NULL,
    ApprovedRatingSum [int] NOT NULL,
    ApprovedTotalReviews [int] NOT NULL,
    VendorId [int] NOT NULL,
    IsTaxExempt [bit] NOT NULL,
    TaxCategoryId [int] NOT NULL,
    Price [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    OldPrice [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    DisableBuyButton [bit] NOT NULL,
    AvailableForPreOrder [bit] NOT NULL,
    SpecialPrice [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc [datetime] NULL,
    SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc [datetime] NULL,
    AvailableStartDateTimeUtc [datetime] NULL,
    AvailableEndDateTimeUtc [datetime] NULL,
    CallForPrice [bit] NOT NULL,
    CustomerEntersPrice [bit]  NULL,
    VendorName [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    SeName [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    Category [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    Manufacturer [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    Tag [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    Picture [nvarchar](max) NULL)


    DECLARE @ProductId INT
DECLARE mapping_cursor CURSOR
FOR

SELECT * FROM [nop_splitstring_to_table](@ProductIds, ',')
--SELECT TOP 80000 ProductId  FROM Incremental_Solr_Product WHERE SolrStatus=1 AND IsDeleted=0 AND StoreId=1

OPEN mapping_cursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM mapping_cursor INTO @ProductId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN


    INSERT INTO #Product 
        (Id,
        Name,
        ShortDescription,
        FullDescription,
        ProductTypeId,
        CreatedOnUtc,
        Sku,
        AllowCustomerReviews,
        ApprovedRatingSum,
        ApprovedTotalReviews,
        VendorId,
        IsTaxExempt,
        TaxCategoryId,
        Price,
        OldPrice,
        DisableBuyButton,
        AvailableForPreOrder,
        SpecialPrice,
        SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc,
        SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc,
        AvailableStartDateTimeUtc,
        AvailableEndDateTimeUtc,
        CallForPrice,
        CustomerEntersPrice,
        VendorName,
        SeName,
        Category,
        Manufacturer,
        Tag,
        Picture)

     SELECT 
        p.Id,
        p.Name,
        p.ShortDescription,
        p.FullDescription,
        p.ProductTypeId,
        p.CreatedOnUtc,
        p.Sku,
        p.AllowCustomerReviews,
        p.ApprovedRatingSum,
        p.ApprovedTotalReviews,
        p.VendorId,
        p.IsTaxExempt,
        p.TaxCategoryId,
        p.Price,
        p.OldPrice,
        p.DisableBuyButton,
        p.AvailableForPreOrder,
        p.SpecialPrice,
        p.SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc,
        p.SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc,
        p.AvailableStartDateTimeUtc,
        p.AvailableEndDateTimeUtc,
        p.CallForPrice,
        p.CustomerEntersPrice,
        v.Name AS 'VendorName',
        u.Slug AS 'SeName',
        (SELECT pcm.Id,pcm.CategoryId,c.Name AS 'CategoryName',pcm.DisplayOrder AS 'CategoryDisplayOrder' FROM Product_Category_Mapping AS pcm JOIN Category AS c ON pcm.CategoryId=c.Id WHERE pcm.ProductId=@ProductId FOR XML RAW ,ROOT('Category')) AS 'Category',
        (SELECT pmm.ManufacturerId ,m.Name,pmm.DisplayOrder  FROM Product_Manufacturer_Mapping AS pmm JOIN Manufacturer AS m ON pmm.ManufacturerId=m.Id WHERE pmm.ProductId=@ProductId FOR XML RAW ,ROOT('Manufacturer')) AS 'Manufacturer',
        (SELECT ptm.ProductTag_Id,t.Name FROM Product_ProductTag_Mapping AS ptm JOIN ProductTag AS t ON ptm.ProductTag_Id=t.Id WHERE ptm.Product_Id=@ProductId FOR XML RAW ,ROOT('Tag')) AS  'Tag',
        (SELECT TOP 1 ppm.PictureId,p.MimeType,p.SeoFilename FROM Product_Picture_Mapping AS ppm LEFT JOIN Picture AS p ON ppm.PictureId=p.Id WHERE ProductId=@ProductId ORDER BY DisplayOrder FOR XML RAW ,ROOT('Picture')) AS  'Picture'
        FROM Product as p LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor AS v ON p.VendorId=v.Id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN UrlRecord AS u ON p.Id=u.EntityId
        WHERE p.Id=@ProductId AND u.EntityName='Product' AND u.LanguageId=0




FETCH NEXT

FROM mapping_cursor INTO @ProductId

END

CLOSE mapping_cursor
DEALLOCATE mapping_cursor


    SELECT * FROM #Product
DROP TABLE #Product 


END     
ELSE
    PRINT 'Provide product ids...'

END
```

Comment: Do you have problem with that? You've marked post with OOM, but no indication of actual problem with you program - just some desire to have less memory usage. If you don't want memory/CPU to be used - take it out of you computer :)

Comment: What are you trying to do - exactly?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are using a SqlReader, your creating a List of objects from your DB query and that's most likely where your memory is going. What consumes the List that you create? How many rows are returned by your query?

Comment: It's just normal application. I've retrieved a data using store procedure and read that data using execute reader and mapped with Product. You also see a code for reference. My concern is, AWE is not release memory. it keep increasing.

Comment: Please include the code that calls GetProducts

Comment: @RalphWillgoss : What is the best practices to store everything from DB?

Comment: what does your stored procedure do, if no Id's are passed in? Can you past that SQL code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter that you are using a SqlReader, your creating a List of objects from your DB query and that's most likely where your memory is going.

Best practice is to bring back the least amount of data possible.

I suspect that your batching logic, is causing memory issues due to the looping you are using to get each batch.

Add some tracing and see how many times each of your db functions are being called.
You may find that one or more functions are being called numerous times, when you expected it to be called only once. Then this will help you narrow down the trouble area.

Comment: I've updated Stored Procedure. SP returns 5000 rows at a time.

Comment: if you pass a single productId into your stored procedure, how many rows does it return?

Comment: If I pass single product id, it returns only one row. I do pass multiple products id like '1,2,3,4,5' then split string and get each product id and process it.

Comment: So when your console app runs and you pass in 1 Id does it still consume all the memory? How many Ids are passed to the app when you were doing your testing?

Comment: I've passed 500 ids for testing and it returns 500 rows. Yes, If I Pass one id, then it consume memory but to get all memory it takes much time to increase memory rather than I pass 500 memory. It means that , in every case it takes memory. If I pass 500 product ids ,memory increase rapidly..

Comment: how much memory does it consume and corresponding rows are returned, if you return 500, 1000 or 5000 records?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48220/discussion-between-dharmik-bhandari-and-ralph-willgoss)

Answer (score 1):

As you are streaming the data into your app, what are you doing with it? It sounds like you're storing something related to each row, which is why your memory consumption continues to climb.

Comment: It's just simple application that uses sql data reader to read data form database and use it.There no hard logic to process data. I'm using simple Sqlreader that's it.

Comment: "to read data form database and use it" What is "use it", exactly? What are you doing? Creating objects and storing them in a collection?  Simply writing strings to console?

Answer (score 0):

If your app loads data into memory then.... it's going to consume memory.

If SQL Server has to do work (providing your app with data) then SQL Server is going to consume memory... and not release it (because that's the way it is built). You can try reducing the maximum memory on your SQL Server to rule this out. SQL Server uses AWE if you've configured it to but it's really only used in 32 bit installations and you have to explicitly configure it that way.

Many non-DB developers don't realise that you can often do the work you want in the database more efficiently with less memory use. Since we don't have all of your code we can't work out if that is the case.

In regards to: What is the best practices to store everything from DB? The best practice is don't store everything from the DB. Leave it in the DB and only get out what you need.